# How to solve value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

I want to get an image from an api and I get the error mentioned in the title.

```
class _ApiState extends State<Api> {
  Future<CatData> fetchcat() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search'));

    // Appropriate action depending upon the
    // server response
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return CatData.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      //return CatData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }

  late Future<CatData> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchcat();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<CatData>(
      future: fetchcat(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Image.network(snapshot.data!.imagen);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

here the class model:

```
class CatData {
  String imagen;

  CatData({required this.imagen});

  factory CatData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CatData(
      imagen: json['url'],
    );
  }
}
```

If I get an answer please, I would like you to explain to me the reason for the problem. because I always get this kind of errors when I consume API's.
"receives one value but expects another"

https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `json.decode(response.body)` gives you back a `List<dynamic>`, but you declared the method `fromJson` to accept one argument of type `Map<String, dynamic>`, thus the incompatibility.
You can change the signature of the method `fromJson` and set it to `List<dynamic>`. Then you could access it with `json[0].url`, `json[0]['url']` or `{url} = json[0]`.
I tested the following code in https://dartpad.dev and works like a charm now.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<CatData> fetchcat() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search'));

    // Appropriate action depending upon the
    // server response
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return CatData.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      //return CatData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
}

class CatData {
  String imagen;

  CatData({required this.imagen});

  factory CatData.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    return CatData(
      imagen: json[0]['url']
    );
  }
}

void main() async {
  CatData catData = await fetchcat();
  print(catData.imagen);
}
```

Comment: it does not work.

Comment: imagen: json[0]['url'],
      thus?

Comment: What does it mean "it does not work"? What is the error?

Comment: still not working

Comment: It still gives the same error as the question title. only now it no longer says it expected a dynamic list and receives a dynamic list

Comment: Can you please formulate again? I didn't get it

Comment: the question? but what do you change? I add the image of the screen?

Comment: Simply, what's the error message after my suggestion?

Comment: I was expecting a dynamic list value but got a dynamic list..   I change the string by the list

Comment: Verify that you declared the class CatData, exactly like my answer

Comment: It should load this image. but it does not work that there are errors with the loading of the image https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search

Comment: sorry sir i had to restart vscode. it worked thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You probably making mistake on casting. first make sure what kind of data you are retrieving means is it key-value pair `{ "url" : "www...." }` or List `[{"url" :"www...} , { "url": " www..."}]`

if its key-value pairs then decode it as follows:

```
final decoded = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
final _catData = CataData.fromJson(decoded);
```

or if its list of urls then do it as follows:

```
final _decoded = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
final _catsData = _decoded.map((e) => CatData.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();
```

Comment: thanks a lot sr i really appreciated that <3